# How to Calculate gyroscope bias given an input vector of measurements w?

Tags: gyroscope

I am developing a GPS-Localizer using accelerometer and gyroscope sensor values. for more accuracy, i want to calculate sensor biases, so i already implemented the accelerometer calculation via matlab using an input vector $ a$ and it looks like this:

```
function [sigma_out, mean_out, bias_out] = aCalibration (a)

sigma_out = std(a, 0, 2);
mean_out = mean(a, 2);

% The direction of the mean acceleraion is assumed to be the direction 
% of gravity (thus down). Any other component is considered bias. This 
% is by no means an acurate representation of the biases. 
bias_out = mean_out - mean_out / norm(mean_out) * 9.81;
```

For the Gyroscope i use an input vector $w$, so i calculate standard deviation and mean like this:

```
function [w_sigma, w_mean, w_bias] = wCalibration (w)

% TODO: implement the sigma/mean/bias computation
w_sigma = std(w,0,2);
w_mean = mean(w,2)
w_bias = [0; 0; 0];
```

How do i calculate the gyroscope bias $b_w$ now? i dont know i think i still need to consider some angular velocity constants but i dont know which ones.... :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do the exact same thing you're doing for the accelerometer.

With the accelerometer, you're assuming that the device isn't *actually* constantly accelerating in any particular direction. You assume that the *net long term acceleration is zero*.

Are you expecting that the gyro is constantly rotating in a particular direction? Or are you assuming that the *net long term rotational speed* is also zero?

The only difference is that you know a "zero reading" of an accelerometer is [0; 0; -g], and the "zero reading" of a gyroscope is [0; 0; 0].

This is all pretty similar to [another answer I gave recently](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/15026/9720). You could essentially use the same function for both, as in something like:

```
function [sigmaOut, meanOut, unknownBias] = Calibrate(data, knownBias)
sigmaOut = std(data);
meanOut = mean(data);
unknownBias = meanOut - knownBias;
end
```

Pass in `[0; 0; -9.81]` for an accelerometer's known bias and `[0; 0; 0]` for the gyro. I'll point out that you don't have any rotations included in your code, so be careful there. Orientation matters!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Actually i just calculated the bias using the formula: $Bias = \sqrt{MSE(w) - Var(w)}$.